# How to create a channel in MQManager?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a code like this.

```
PCFMessageAgent pcfMessageAgent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManagerName);    
PCFMessage createChannel = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_CREATE_CHANNEL);
createChannel.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACF_TO_CHANNEL_NAME, "NEW.CHANNEL.NAME");
pcfMessageAgent.send(createChannel);
```

What parameters do I need to add in order to create a channel?

Comment: Please view the instructions for using the MQCMD_CREATE_CHANNEL PCF command here (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086930_.htm). This shows you the required parameters and the optional parameters. Some additional parameters are required depending on the channel type you are creating. Since you don't say which type of channel you are trying to make, I can't say further which ones you should use. If you update your question to say what you need to create, I can create an answer accordingly.

Comment: If you know what your channel needs to look like - add that to your question.